# Calculate destination point with distance and bearing from initial point EXCEL

Tags: excel

Hi I am using an interpretation of the Haversine formula to calculate destination coordinates from inputted original coordinates, distance and bearing:

The formula I am using are:

```
lat2: =ASIN(SIN(lat1)*COS(d/ER) + COS(lat1)*SIN(d/ER)*COS(brng))
lon2: =lon1 + ATAN2(COS(d/ER)-SIN(lat1)*SIN(lat2), SIN(brng)*SIN(d/ER)*COS(lat1))
```

In my example, I have used the values of:

```
lat1 = 52.239764
lat2 = -0.904089
d = 10
ER = 6371
brng = 270
```

The values found are:

```
lat2 = 1.165765924 and lon2 = -0.903387754
```

When using the example found at:

```
http://www.catalina-capri-25s.org/tech/latlongcalc.asp
```

the values should be 52.239722 and -1.050833. I have confirmed this is correct by using google maps and seeing it as 10km west of original point location.

Is the problem something to do with radians maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Excel does use radians in its trig functions.  I am not sure about VBA but I would assume so.  As such you will need to convert your degrees to radians before using it in your formula (or embed the conversion in the formula.  If you were doing it in an excel cell formula it would be:

```
=RADIANS(brng)
`where brng is a named cells holding an angle measured in degrees
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything needs to be in radians, so as well as the bearing, you have to change the decimal degrees to radians too or it won't work. I.e. use radians(lat1) and radians(lon1).

Remember your output is now in radians, so convert back using degrees(lat2) and degrees(long2)